# UITextView in UITableView iPad

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uitextview

I'm trying to add a UITextView in a UITableViewCell for the iPad, and for some reason my UITextView is not taking up the whole height/width of the UITableViewCell.  Here's how I declare the cell

```
UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
[textView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[cell.contentView addSubview:textView];
```

though it looks like this
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `cell.contentView.frame`?

Comment: Whats the result when you print that frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

autoresizing masks worked...flexwidth and flexheight

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `textView.contentSize = [cell.contentView.frame.size]`;

Comment: UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];textView.contentSize = cell.contentView.frame.size; did not work...result was teh same

Answer (score 0):

You want the size to be (cell.contentView.frame.size.width, cell.contentView.frame.size.height) and the origin to be (0,0). 
Then add it to the cell.contentView. The frame origin is relative to the textView's superview, which in this case would be the cell.contentView.

Comment: textView.frame = cell.contentView.frame did not work...result was the same

Comment: Did you set the origin to 0,0? I think that's the change you need